# How Can I get Internet Explorer To Play My Video

Tags: video, internet-explorer

I have a website:

www.nurseresumetips.com

I'm using Flowplayer to play a h.264 encoded video. This works on all browzers including ios devices.

The problem is with Internet Explorer. I'm running ie 9 and the video won't play unless the user turns on compatibility mode.

I'm using a Wordpress plugin JVPress.

I want to wave a magic wand and make is so my video plays automatically in any version of IE 7 and above.

And advice?

Thanks

Comment: This question seems to be off topic here on SuperUser, it should maybe migrated to wordpress.SE or webapps.SE.

Comment: Or perhaps webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: People uses to "migrate" these questions. Isn't this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here it appears you're actually using Longtail's JW Player, version 5.3.1397.

You should update to a newer version (they're up to v5.10), as the IE9 compatibility bug was reportedly fixed around v5.5.

You can check it out at their [home page](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) for more info and to obtain a newer version.

Comment: That's it!!!! I could kiss you!!!!